# Hölder continuity of measure associated to Nevanlinna function

Tags: complex-analysis, measure-theory

Let $F$ be a Nevanlinna function and $\mu$ the (via Stieltjes inversion formula) associated measure, which is a finite Borel measure on $\mathbb R$ and let $C(\lambda)$ be the function ($\alpha \in (0,1]$ fixed) $C(\lambda) = sup_{\varepsilon \in (0,1]} \varepsilon^{1-\alpha} Im(F(\lambda+ i \varepsilon))$, which is assumed to be locally bounded.
By using the Stieltjes inversion formula and a trivial integral estimate I 
confirmed for myself the estimate
$\mu(\lambda-\varepsilon,\lambda+\varepsilon) \leq 2 \varepsilon Im(F(\lambda+i \varepsilon))$.

Now i want to show under the above assumptions ($C(\lambda)$ locally bounded) that $\mu$ is Hölder continuous with exponent $\alpha$. To that end, we have for $\varepsilon \leq 1$ and for some $\lambda$, by above estimate and by definition of $C(\lambda)$:

$\frac{\mu(\lambda-\varepsilon,\lambda+\varepsilon)}{(2 \varepsilon)^\alpha} \leq 2^{1-\alpha}C(\lambda)$.

My problem is, that I dont see how I can deduce that there is a uniform constant $K$ such that for all $\lambda$ and all $\varepsilon > 0$ we have
$\frac{\mu(\lambda-\varepsilon,\lambda+\varepsilon)}{(2 \varepsilon)^\alpha} \leq K$.
Do I have to use some property of Nevanlinna functions?

Edit: If one says that a measure $\mu$ is Hölder continuous, what is usually meant? At first, i thought it means there exists a $K>0$ and an $\alpha$ such that for any interval $[a,b]$ we have $\mu([a,b]) \leq K |b-a|^\alpha$. What else could be meant?